# Controlled Bandwidth Performance testing in Jmeter using CPS value

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, response-time, cps

I am trying t control the bandwidth in Jmeter using CPS value at runtime. But it is not giving the accurate results. I have also changed implementation type to httpclient4 in Http request defaults.
**Command Used : ** *jmeter -Jhttpclient.socket.http.cps=12800 -Jhttpclient.socket.https.cps=12800 -n -t [JMX path] -l [Results path]*
Is there any other way to control the bandwidth in jmeter?
Or is there any way to confirm the CPS value in jmeter like printing it in logs?

That the jmeter test should run with controlled bandwidth value and give accurate results

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware this is the only way to implement throttling in JMeter i.e. for simulating slow networks like Wi-Fi or mobile. See [Controlling Bandwidth in JMeter to simulate different networks](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/Controlling+Bandwidth+in+JMeter+to+simulate+different+networks)

The easiest way of checking this is:

1. Running the test with these 2 properties enabled
2. Running the test with these 2 properties set to 0 or not set

In the 2nd case you should see higher throughput and higher number of samplers executed in the same time frame.

Of course the settings are applicable only for [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler, if your test assumes other protocols - other Samplers won't be impacted.

Alternative way of slowing JMeter down would be using [JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer), Timers won't simulate slow networks but you can control the frequency of Samplers execution

Comment: is there a way to confirm that test is running with give CPS value only? Like can we print the CPS value in logs by any way?